# time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Time ago in words is returning me a stack error too deep error. Here how i call it.

```
<%= link_to time_ago_in_words(f.created_at), f %>
```

And here what i did, in article.helper

```
def time_ago_in_words(time_str)
    time = time_str.to_time + (-Time.zone_offset(Time.now.zone))
    "happened #{time_ago_in_words(time)} ago"
end
```

Can't i redefine time_ago_in_words? because i also try the follow and it gave me the same kind of error

```
<%= link_to ctime_ago_in_words(f.created_at), f %>


def ctime_ago_in_words(time_str)
    time = time_str.to_time + (-Time.zone_offset(Time.now.zone))
    "happened #{ctime_ago_in_words(time)} ago"
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Original:

```
def ctime_ago_in_words(time_str)
    time = time_str.to_time + (-Time.zone_offset(Time.now.zone))
    "happened #{ctime_ago_in_words(time)} ago"
end
```

You still have a function that repeatedly calls itself. I think you meant this instead for that last line:

```
"happened #{time_ago_in_words(time)} ago"
```